# Client reads lesser bytes than Server is sending on sockets

Tags: c, sockets

My server code is as follows:

```
while(bytes_written < filesize){
                    //Send from send_ptr
                    bw = send(child_socket, send_ptr, newLength, 0);
                    printf("%d bytes written\n", (int)bw);
                    //Increment bytes written
                    bytes_written += bw;
                    //Move send pointer
                    send_ptr = send_ptr + bw;
}
```

And my client code is as follows:

```
while((num_bytes_recv = read(sd, jpgBufferPointer, BUFFER_LENGTH))>0){
        total_bytes_recv += num_bytes_recv;
        printf("Read %d bytes\n",num_bytes_recv);

        //Check for error
        if(jpgError == NULL)
            jpgError = strstr(jpgBufferPointer, "404 Not Found");

        if(jpgError != NULL){
            //Forwarding error response
            if(send(sd, jpgBuffer, num_bytes_recv, 0) == -1){
                error("Failed to send response message to client"); 
            }
        }   
        else{
            //Find content size
            contentSizeBuffer = strstr(jpgBufferPointer,"Content-Length");

            if(contentSizeBuffer != NULL){
                contentSizeBuffer=contentSizeBuffer+16;
                contentSize=atoi(contentSizeBuffer);                    
                jpgBuffer=(char*)realloc(jpgBuffer,(contentSize+FILE_NAME_LENGTH*2)*sizeof(char));
                jpgBufferPointer=jpgBuffer;
            }
            jpgBufferPointer+=num_bytes_recv;
        }
    }
```

The server is saying it has sent all 43000 bytes, but client says it has received only 32768 bytes.

Appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: Whenever I see a nice power of two, I'd be suspicious. That's not your `BUFFER_LENGTH`, is it?

Comment: My BUFFER_LENGTH is 100000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in the sending part, you should update newLength, because if you have 1 byte left to send from the file, it will send more, going out of the memory area where the content you want to send is stored. You should fix in this way:

```
bw = send(child_socket, send_ptr, newLength<(filesize-bytes_written)?newLength:(filesize-bytes_written), 0);
```

In this way the last send will have the correct size.

Also, use write instead of send if you are not using any flags.

Comment: That almost works for me.
The same problem comes up for:
    while(bytes_written < filesize)
but if I make it:
    while(bytes_written <= filesize)
it goes into an infinite loop even when bw = 0, and it is not closing the socket.So the client has read all the bytes, but is waiting for it to close. So if I force the server to close, the image shows up on the browser.

Comment: Of course you end up in an infinite loop if you use bytes_written <= filesize... Basically when you have written all the file and bytes_written = filesize, that will still evaluate as true and will keep looping.

Comment: That's true, but changing the <= to < makes the previous problem reappear. I still have a bug somewhere in that loop.

Comment: You never said your client was a browser or that you were using HTTP. If you are using HTTP/0.9 (the easy one to implement) just close the socket after the while in the server.

Comment: I tried closing the socket and that too didn't work, but you would be surprised to know what did. I had to put a usleep(1) after each write. I am not sure why it was needed, but it worked. Thanks though, would have never thought of the memory overshoot!

Comment: If you need to put sleep in your code, you certainly have bugs, they are not supposed to be used like this. Please post more about your server

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the similar loop as you have on the writing side (bytes_written < filesize) on the reading side (i.e., while you can read more bytes, you should read them and append them).

The network doesn't guarantee that one read() call will return all available data.

Comment: ^ Doesn't the while((num_bytes_recv = read(sd, jpgBufferPointer, BUFFER_LENGTH))>0) do that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way of writing client-server socket programming is to have a header before your data. The header should state the amount of data that it is going to transfer.

For example, To send data "Hello World", then send it as "0011+HELLO WORLD"

Here 11 stands for the size of the data the sender is planning to send now. The receiver on reading the first 4 bytes can understand that he should be ready to read next 11 bytes of data from the sender.

So reader will do two read:
     hRead = 5 /* With 5 you are saying it can read upto max of 9999 bytes from data". 
     read(sd, buff, hRead);
     dRead = atoi(buff);
     readn(sd, buff, dRead);

For Example : Server

```
 size_t sendn(int fd, const void *vptr, size_t n) {
   size_t nleft;
   size_t nwritten;
   const char *ptr;

   ptr = vptr;
   nleft = n;
   while (nleft > 0) {
       if ((nwritten = send(fd, vptr, nleft, 0)) <= 0) {
          if (errno == EINTR)
               nwritten = 0;
          else {
              fprintf(stderr, "send failed  %d - %s\n", fd, strerror(errno));
              return (-1);
          }
        }
        nleft -= nwritten;
        ptr += nwritten;
   }
   return (n);
  }
```

To send message:

```
  sprintf(buff, "%d + %d + %s\r\n", MSG_LOGIN, strlen("Hello World"), Hello World);
  sendn(sd, buff, strlen(buff));
```

Client:

```
 size_t readn(int fd, void *vptr, size_t n) {
  size_t nleft;
  size_t nread;
  char *ptr;

  ptr = vptr;
  nleft = n;
  while (nleft > 0) {
      if ((nread = recv(fd, ptr, nleft, 0)) < 0) {
          if (errno == EINTR)
              nread = 0;
          else {
              fprintf(stderr, "read failed %d - %s\n", fd, strerror(errno));
              return (-1);
          }
      } else if (nread == 0)
          break;

      nleft -= nread;
      ptr += nread;
  }
  return (n - nleft);
}
```